# NSDateFormatter and /'s

Tags: objective-c

I have a NSString that I want to load into a NSDate.  The string looks like: 21/10/2011 5:42:02 PM

What I have written is:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"d/M/yyyy h:mm:ss a"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateString];
```

The date ends up with a null value.

There is obviously something wrong with the date formatter but I am not sure what.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It works fine for me. Have you checked that dateString isn't nil? You're also leaking dateFormat.

Comment: Thanks for checking... the date string is not nil.  There must be something else in the string that I am missing.

Comment: I just manually set the string value and the format works for me as well.  The dates that I am reading in from the file obviously have something else in them that I cannot see.  Thanks for the reply.

Comment: If you're reading them from a file, then maybe they contain a newline character. Try `NSLog(@"%i", [stringFromFile length])` and see if the string has the expected length (21 if I counted correctly)

Comment: Thanks... the newline char was the issue. I used: dateString = [dateString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]; to fix it.

Comment: Glad that solved it. Go ahead and mark @bryanmac's answer as the correct one because it kind of is the same as what I said here in the comments. Otherwise this question will be without an answer while you did actually solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the string doesn't match the format, then it will return null.

For example, here's an example that matches the format and one that doesn't:

```
NSString *dateString = @"11/09/2011 12:22:02";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"d/M/yyyy h:mm:ss"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateString];
NSLog(@"dateString; %@", date);

NSString *dateString2 = @"2011-11-09 12:22:02 +0000";
NSDate *date2 = [dateFormat2 dateFromString:dateString2];
NSLog(@"dateString; %@", date2);
```

This outputs:

```
2011-11-09 07:27:54.342 Craplet[45608:707] dateString; 2011-09-11 05:22:02 +0000
2011-11-09 07:27:54.343 Craplet[45608:707] dateString; (null)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I understand that I will get null returned if the format is not matched.  I just cannot see what is wrong with the format I have set.